# Divi Engine - Divi Form Builder - How to request admin approval for new subscribers?

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am using Divi Engine - Divi Form Builder to create User Registration Form.

I achieved the target and the user is created successfully. However, the new subscribers are **automatically approved**. I need the accounts to be created in **pending status** and **require the admin to approve it manually** (the way it's done using Ultimate Member).